# How can I create SQL Server Users based on build configuration using SSDT?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-data-tools

I am new to SSDT so hopefully this is an easy one.  I would like to script different users based on build configuration in my database project.  Is the only way to accomplish that by using SQLCMD variables and Post Deployment Scripts?

Comment: As of now I am just setting the build action on the user to none or build depending on which user I want to be scripted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike, as far as I know the only easy-ish way to do this is with SQLCMD variables and post-deploy scripts. You could probably code something that would parse the generated script and tweak it for each environment, but using the post-deploy scripts will be far easier in the long run.

I've blogged about this, building on Jamie Thomson's idea.
http://schottsql.blogspot.com/2013/05/ssdt-setting-different-permissions-per.html